# Best practices for working with 2d arrays in clojure?

Tags: clojure, multidimensional-array

I am building a minesweeper where the gameboard is a 2d array.

To generate the board I need to get a 2d array, randomly place some bombs, calculate all neighboring bombs for each field, then pack all together with another value (is-revealed) into a Map that should be the final value of each field.

It seems that to do all of this, I need the help of functions like map, filter, nth or zip, but instead of working on lists, they should work on a 2d array. I already started building those, but it seems like the wrong path to go.

Is there some cool abstraction that helps me use the existing functions on the 2d array? Or are there any functions already existing, that deal with 2d arrays?

edit: The way I was doing it - before thinking to myself, that there should be a better way - is something like this:

```
(defn mapmap [f xxs]
  (for [xs xxs]
    (map f xs)))

(defn mapmap-coords [f xxs]
  (for [[i xs] (map-indexed list xxs)]
    (map-indexed (fn [j x] (f j i)) xs)))

(defn get-value [board x y]
  (if (or (< x 0) (< y 0) (< (dec (count board)) y))
    false
    (let [xs (nth board y)]
      (if (< (dec (count xs)) x)
        false
        (nth xs x)))))
```

Comment: https://github.com/mikera/core.matrix

Answer (score 2):

`for` works for nested sequential data.

```
user> (def game-state
       (let [game '[[_ _ _ _]
                    [1 1 _ _]
                    [! 1 _ _]
                    [1 1 _ _]]]
         (for [[i row] (map-indexed list game)
               [j cell] (map-indexed list row)
               :when (not= '_ cell)]
              {:x i :y j :value cell})))
#'user/game-state
user> (pprint game-state)
({:x 1, :y 0, :value 1}
 {:x 1, :y 1, :value 1}
 {:x 2, :y 0, :value !}
 {:x 2, :y 1, :value 1}
 {:x 3, :y 0, :value 1}
 {:x 3, :y 1, :value 1})
nil
```

We can use `reduce` to build up the data structure again (of course any transformations to the state could have been done in between).

```
user> (let [empty-game (vec (repeat 4 '[_ _ _ _]))
            fill-cell (fn [game, {:keys [x y value]}] (assoc-in game [x y] value))
            game (reduce   fill-cell empty-game game-state)]
        (doseq [row game] (apply println row)))
_ _ _ _
1 1 _ _
! 1 _ _
1 1 _ _
nil
```

Comment: Thanks. I see how `for` can be used to unwrap my board and do stuff, but how would i wrap it up again (into another board)?

Comment: Is this the "idiomatic" way to work with 2d arrays? It seems a little complex. So far I had functions like `(defn mapmap [f xxs] (for [xs xxs] (map f xs)))` which can achieve similar things more easily. Is using a 2d array even a clojury thing to do?

Comment: If you want to keep the nested shape, that works. But if you want to work on a single sequence it can make sense to create the flattened version, do some operations on that, and then rebuild the 2d array. Also if you use `mapv` instead of `for` and `map` you get the nice property of associativeness (so you can use `get-in` to access a specific cell of the grid, or `update-in` or `assoc-in` to update a single cell and leave the rest unchanged).

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to drop down into Java types for your implementation, consider using

- [clojure.core/to-array-2d](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/to-array-2d) to create your 2d array and then
- [clojure.core/aget](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/aget) to index into it.

`aget` will give you a more natural method for accessing the array, but you'll still need to build further abstractions to get neighbours and perform updates to (i.e., regenerate) this data structure.